# Error (non-exhaustive patterns) when running function

Tags: haskell

The following code takes as input a 16-bit binary number in the form of a String and returns the first four bits as a hexadecimal. When testing, it compiles, but gives a non=exhaustive patterns in function error at runtime

```
getFirstHex :: String -> String
getFirstHex s  
   |(Data.List.take 12 s) == "0000" = "0"
   |(Data.List.take 12 s) == "0001" = "1"
   |(Data.List.take 12 s) == "0010" = "2"
   |(Data.List.take 12 s) == "0011" = "3"
   |(Data.List.take 12 s) == "0100" = "4"
   |(Data.List.take 12 s) == "0101" = "5"
   |(Data.List.take 12 s) == "0110" = "6"
   |(Data.List.take 12 s) == "0111" = "7"
   |(Data.List.take 12 s) == "1000" = "8"
   |(Data.List.take 12 s) == "1001" = "9"
   |(Data.List.take 12 s) == "1010" = "A"
   |(Data.List.take 12 s) == "1011" = "B"
   |(Data.List.take 12 s) == "1100" = "C"
   |(Data.List.take 12 s) == "1101" = "D"
   |(Data.List.take 12 s) == "1110" = "E"
   |(Data.List.take 12 s) == "1111" = "F"
```

Comment: You take twelve elements from your list and ask if they're equal to a four-element string. Can you think of a situation where that's *ever* true?

Comment: the final case need to be `otherwise`. What to do if the String doesn't equal all those things. But then you'll run into other problems.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo if `length s == 4` - for example `take 12 "abcd" == "abcd"` holds - but yes that's gonna be a problem for sure ;)

Answer (score 2):

as others pointed out the problem is mainly the `take 12` in your version - here is one that should work:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE TupleSections #-}

type HexRep = Char
type BinRep = Char

getFirstHex :: [BinRep] -> Maybe (HexRep, [BinRep])
getFirstHex (a:b:c:d:rest) = (,rest) <$> getHex [a,b,c,d]
    where
    getHex "0000" = pure '0'
    getHex "0001" = pure '1'
    getHex "0010" = pure '2'
    getHex "0011" = pure '3'
    getHex "0100" = pure '4'
    getHex "0101" = pure '5'
    getHex "0110" = pure '6'
    getHex "0111" = pure '7'
    getHex "1000" = pure '8'
    getHex "1001" = pure '9'
    getHex "1010" = pure 'A'
    getHex "1011" = pure 'B'
    getHex "1100" = pure 'C'
    getHex "1101" = pure 'D'
    getHex "1110" = pure 'E'
    getHex "1111" = pure 'F'
    getHex _ = Nothing
getFirstHex _ = Nothing

toHex :: [BinRep] -> ([HexRep], [BinRep])
toHex binRep =
    case getFirstHex binRep of
        Just (hex, rest) -> 
            let (restRes, notConvertible) = toHex rest 
            in (hex:restRes, notConvertible)
        Nothing -> ([], binRep)
```

this one returns `Nothing` if it cannot find anything to represent in hex and the `toHex` function uses is in a way so that you get *best* parsable prefix and the rest that could not be transformed back:

```hs
> toHex "111011001001001"
("EC9","001")
```

---

if you don't like the (admittedly ugly) pattern-match solution - here is one using `splitAt`:

```hs
getFirstHex :: [BinRep] -> Maybe (HexRep, [BinRep])
getFirstHex rep =
    let (first4, rest) = splitAt 4 rep
    in (,rest) <$> getHex first4
    where
    getHex "0000" = pure '0'
    ...
    getHex "1111" = pure 'F'
    getHex _ = Nothing
```